# R: strange behavior when trying to find index of vector equal to a value

Tags: r, indexing, match

I have a simple task of choosing an element in one vector, and trying to find the index of its value in a second vector. This should be simple and straightforward.

Here are two example vectors:

```
vec1 <- seq(-0.2,1.5,0.02)
vec2 <- seq(-0.1,1.5,0.02)
```

Through some other process, I'm picking an index from `vec1`, in this case 43:

```
i=43
val.to.search.for <- vec1[43]
str(val.to.search.for)
num 0.64
```

If I search for this in `vec2` using the usual approaches, I don't get any values returned:

```
which( vec2 %in% val.to.search.for )
integer(0)
which( vec2 == val.to.search.for )
integer(0)
```

However, if I explicitly search for the number 0.64, I get the proper index:

```
which( vec2 %in% 0.64 )
[1] 38
which( vec2 == 0.64 )
[1] 38
```

Searching in the original vector works:

```
which( vec1 %in% val.to.search.for)
[1] 43
which( vec1 == val.to.search.for)
[1] 43
```

This seems like it should be a straightforward coding problem, but clearly there is something I do not understand. Why do the `which()` calls for `vec2` not return anything when I'm using the variable?

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with matching floating point numbers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558.  Compare `sprintf("%.20f",vec1[43])` vs. 
`sprintf("%.20f",vec2[38])`. They are close to the same, but not the same numbers. Not all functions use the same definitions of "close enough," which is why you are seeing inconsistent results.

Comment: When attempting non-integral equality in floating-point numbers, I suggest the use of the absolute-difference under a tolerance. For example, `abs(vec2 - val.to.search.for) < 1e-9` returns `38`. This "situation" is not unique to R, it is common among many/most(/all?) programming languages that do not natively support arbitrary-precision of this nature.

Comment: Computers have limitations when it comes to floating-point numbers (aka `double`, `numeric`, `float`). This is a fundamental limitation of computers in general, in how they deal with non-integer numbers. This is not specific to any one programming language. There are some add-on libraries or packages that are much better at arbitrary-precision math, but I believe most main-stream languages (this is relative/subjective, I admit) do not use these by default. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518, https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: If I have misunderstood, or you are not convinced, after reading some of the links (they are sleeping-pills in a sense :-), feel free to @-ping me and we can discuss further your questions.

Comment: Thanks all! Yes, I should have realized this was a floating point error. Since the comparisons are for floats with only a couple digits of precision, it's easy enough to use `which(abs(vec2-val.to.search.for)<1e-9)` as suggested by **r2evans** to select the correct index.